# How to get absolute difference amongst all the values of a column with each other?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to find difference among-st all values in key column keeping these 4 digit code as my index value.
I tried using pivot for this operation but failed.
It would be really helpful if I can get the approach for this presentation.

**df1**

```
Name | Key | 1001 | 1002 | 1003 |
Abb    AB      5      8      10     
Baa    BA     10     11      33  
Cbb    CB     12     40      90
```

**Expected df**

```
Code  | Key | AB | BA | CB |
1001    AB     0   5    7
1001    BA     5   0    2
1001    CB     7   2    0
1002
.
.
.
1003
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the best solution though.

**df:**

```
    Name    Key 1001 1002 1003
0   Abb     AB  5    8    10
1   Baa     BA  10   11   33
2   Cbb     CB  12   40   90
```

---

```
df1 = df.set_index(['Name','Key']).T
```

**df1:**

```
Name    Abb Baa Cbb
Key     AB  BA  CB
1001    5   10  12
1002    8   11  40
1003    10  33  90
```

---

```
df2 = df1.loc[np.repeat(df1.index.values,len(df1.columns))] 
df2.columns = df2.columns.droplevel(0)
```

**df2:**

```
Key     AB  BA  CB
1001    5   10  12
1001    5   10  12
1001    5   10  12
1002    8   11  40
1002    8   11  40
1002    8   11  40
1003    10  33  90
1003    10  33  90
1003    10  33  90
```

---

```
x = df1.unstack().swaplevel(0,2).sort_index()
```

**x:**

```
      Key  Name
1001  AB   Abb      5
      BA   Baa     10
      CB   Cbb     12
1002  AB   Abb      8
      BA   Baa     11
      CB   Cbb     40
1003  AB   Abb     10
      BA   Baa     33
      CB   Cbb     90
dtype: int64
```

---

```
df3 = df2.sub(x.values, axis=0).abs()
```

**df3:**

```
Key     AB  BA  CB
1001    0   5   7
1001    5   0   2
1001    7   2   0
1002    0   3   32
1002    3   0   29
1002    32  29  0
1003    0   23  80
1003    23  0   57
1003    80  57  0
```